# Running Python code in Visual Studio - installing pip not working

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip

I`m trying to connect Linkedin to my Python.
and I`m trying to run these in Visual Studio

For the below line,

$ pip install python-linkedin

it keeps throwing syntax error, not reading that $pip correctly.

I followed few videos and posts on Stackoverflow, and they suggested to click on "View" -> "Tools" -> Python environments, but I can`t find this "Tool" and Python environments from View option

Is there any alternative solutions to this?

Screenshot is my Visual Studio setting, if it helps..
[VS setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYJ6k.png)

Comment: you don't type also the `$`, right?

Comment: Nope, only starting from "p".

Comment: aha, you type it in the file. that is something you need to write in the integrated Terminal. if you don't see it, go View ->Terminal (Ctrl+`)

Answer (score -1):

You need to install Python support for VS to work with python.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/installing-python-support-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Once you do that you should be able to see the python environment tab. It would look like this: [image]

Another potential issue is that pip for python3.x is usually installed as pip3.x, not pip, so if you are using python 3x, you would need to change your settings.json accordingly.